# Is there a way of applying a function to each member of a struct in c++?

Tags: c++

You have a simple struct, say:

```
struct rect
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

And you want to multiply each element by a factor.  Is there a more concise way of performing this operation, other than multiplying each member by the value?

Comment: If all members of the same type, can't you put them in an array (`int members_[ 4 ];`? And provide accessors (`int rect::x() const;`) and mutators ( `void rect::x( int );`)? You have to write code one place or the other :)

Comment: When defining types in C++, lose the typedef.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really. Programatically obtaining a list of the elements of a struct requires reflection, which C++ does not support.

Your two options are to just give the struct a method that does this the long-winded way and then use that method in all other places, or to manually mimic reflection, for example by giving the struct another element which is an array of pointers to all of its other elements (built within the struct's constructor), and then looping over that to perform the scaling function.

Comment: What about unions? In particular, Microsoft's usage of them in D3DXMATRIX and D3DXVECTOR.

Comment: That's really the same thing as the casting solution that others have posted, but with a nicer syntax. It is similarly reliant on the behavior of a particular compiler and standard C++ doesn't guarantee that it will work.

Comment: Not an exhaustive list of options. You can use pointers of **pointer-to-member** type, as suggested in my answer. This is similar to your second option, but in that case you wouldn't have to create a separate pointer array for each struct instance. Instead you use a single array that is applicable to all instances (you can make it *static* member of the struct if you want). In fact, *this* is the correct way to "manually mimic reflection", not what you suggest above.

Answer (score 11):

No; there is no way to iterate over the members of a struct.

In this particular case, though, you can accomplish your goal by using an array:

```
struct rect
{
    // actually store the data in an array, not as distinct elements
    int values_[4];

    // use accessor/mutator functions to modify the values; it is often best to
    // provide const-qualified overloads as well.
    int& x()      { return values_[0]; }
    int& y()      { return values_[1]; }
    int& width()  { return values_[2]; }
    int& height() { return values_[3]; }

    void multiply_all_by_two()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(values_) / sizeof(values_[0]); ++i)
            values_[i] *= 2;
    }
};
```

(note that this example doesn't make much sense (why would you multiply x, y, height and width by two?) but it demonstrates a different way to solve this sort of problem)

Comment: Some suggestions, although outside the scope of the original question: (i) Use a symbolic constant instead of `4`. (ii) Accept the multiplier (`2` in the example) as an input argument.

Comment: I can easily think of an example where you'd want to multiply all those values by two: when you've changed units. If you've halved your unit size (e.g. going from meters to half meters, or doubling resolution in an image so pixels are half as small), but kept rect the same real world size, you need to double all of it's values.

Answer (score 10):

[Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) offers the [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) macro, which can turn any struct into a Fusion sequence, which Fusion can then iterate over (as demoed in the [Quick Start](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/quick_start.html)).

Another option is to use a third-party C++ reflection library like [Reflex](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/reflex) to iterate over a struct's members.

However, all of this may be overkill for your purposes; manually listing each of the class's members may be less elegant, but it's much simpler, and simplicity in coding is important.

Comment: +1 for `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`: the quickest way to get compile-time reflexion.

Answer (score 5):

If all the values fit into a 128-bit vector, then you could use SIMD instructions to multiply them all at once. For example Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP) has [primitives](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ipps/ipps_ch5/functn_MulC.html) for addition, subtraction, multiplication etc. on vectors.

It's probably overkill unless you are doing a lot of compute intensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

If all are the **same type**, use a union combined with an anonymous struct, inside of your struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
  union {
    int data[4];
    struct {
      int x,y,z,w;
    }
  };
};
```

then:

```
MyStruct my_struct;
cout << my_struct.x << my_struct.y << my_struct.z << my_struct.w;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  some_function(my_struct.data[i]); // access the data via "data" member
cout << my_struct.x << my_struct.y << my_struct.z << my_struct.w; // voila!, stryct data has changed!
```

If youre using **different types** have a look at [boost::fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: this is ugly and horrible, but it probably the best way of doing exactly what the OP asked for... +1

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone has said, you can't do it directly, but there's nothing stopping you from overloading the * operator:

```
struct rect 
{ 
   int x; 
   int y; 
   int width; 
   int height; 
}

rect operator*(const rect& r, int f)
{
  rect ret=r;
  ret.x*=f;
  ret.y*=f;
  ret.width*=f;
  ret.height*=f;
  return ret;
}
```

then you can do this

```
rect r;
//assign fields here
r=r*5;
```

Comment: This is is only clean solution so far... I had to remove my answer, you were faster

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a C++ compiler (not C), make it a class and create a member function to do this.  I am suprised at all the awkward solutions presented to a simple problem.  What does a reflective solution buy you?  Are you continually adding new members to this class, so you want to save yourself the step of modifying the member function in the future?  If that is a seriously a potential time-saver, it smells of a class doing too much.

It is inevitable there will be repeated functionality acting on the members of a structure, so why not make it a class from the start?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not directly. But you can achieve that by using an additional temporary "index" array of pointers of pointer-to-member type.

For example

```
rect a_rect[100];
int factor;
...
// We need to multiply all members of all elements of `a_rect` array by `factor`

// Prepare index array
int rect::*rect_members[4] = { &rect::x, &rect::y, &rect::width, &rect::height };

// And multiply
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    a_rect[i].*rect_members[j] *= factor;
```

Of course, if you need to do it often, you can use a permanent index array `rect_members` initialized at the program startup.

Note that this method does not employ any hacks, as some other methods do. Pointers of pointer-to-member type are rarely used, but this is actually one of the things they were introduced for.

Again, if you need to do it often, the proper thing to do would be to make the pointer array a `static const` member of the struct

```
struct rect
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int width;
  int height;

  static int rect::* const members[4];
};

int rect::* const rect::members[4] = { &rect::x, &rect::y, &rect::width, &rect::height };
```

and when you need to iterate over these members, you'd just access struct elements as `s.*rect::members[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

if all your elements are of the same type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(rect) / sizeof(rect.x) ; ++i) {
    do_something(reinterpret_cast<int *>(adress_of_your_struct) + i);
}
```

with `do_something` expecting a pointer to `int`

Comment: This isn't portable because it assumes that there is no padding between the elements of the structure, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: code brevity at the cost of type safety. still, very concise. +1

Comment: @Andrew:  Type safety should _never_ be sacrificed for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @James: What about when you have 6 minutes to solve a programming puzzle at an ACM programming competition?

Comment: @Andrew:  I can start prefixing my commentary with "when writing real-world software that has real-world requirements," if you think that would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

horrific hack

```
int *arr = (int*)&my_rect;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(rect)/sizeof(int); i++)
{
     arr[i] *= factor;
}
```

Comment: This isn't portable because it assumes that there is no padding between the elements of the structure, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: well duh, hence 'horrible hack'. It will work on most 32 bits machines tho

Answer (score 0):

A solution via a new class:

- Create a class with a `template<class T> class Array` generic array, (see [how](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0260__template/Defineyourowngenericarray.htm)),
- Fill the array with your properties, one property as an element of the array.
- Ensure all types can be multiplied by a numeric value (or  overload the `*` operator for a type if necessary / create a specific method for that object)
- Create a method `multiply` that performs a loop on the array and multiplies each element by a given value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can re-arrange your struct to take be a union instead, you can do something similar to what Microsoft has done with DirectX.

```
union Rect
{
    struct
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
    };

    int members[4];
};

void multiply(Rect& rect, int factor)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        rect.members[i] *= factor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues associated with inheriting from standard classes; but if you're willing to accept those issues, you can do something analagous to what others have suggested, but using `std::valarray` instead.  It would look something like:

```
#include <valarray>

class rect : public std::valarray<int>
{
  public:
    rect() : std::valarray(4, 0) {}

    int& x() { return (*this)[0]; }
    int& y() { return (*this)[1]; }
    int& width() { return (*this)[2]; }
    int& height() { return (*this)[3]; }
};
```

With this, you inherit the vector operations defined on `std::valarray<int>`.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach.  I merely suggest that it can be done.